shunit2 gives 'command not found' error while executing
I have a shell script to which I am trying to write the unit test code by mocking the data.
Intention of the actual logic:
script automates the extraction of file changes between two Git commits and saves them in a specific directory. It includes logging and error handling to ensure that the process is traceable and reliable.
When I run the script I am thrown with the following errors
`$ ./test_extract_delta.sh
testScriptExecution
../../shunit2/shunit2/shunit2: line 1125: testScriptExecution: command not found
shunit2:ERROR testScriptExecution() returned non-zero return code.
Ran 1 test.`
I am unsure what has already gone wrong in my script? Can someone please point it to me if possible?
Following is my unit test code
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# Load shUnit2
. ../../shunit2/shunit2/shunit2

# Setup mock environment
setUp() {
    # Mocking environment variables
    export EXTRACT_DELTA_CONSOLE_LOG_PATH="/tmp/extract_delta_console_log"
    export MINIMIZED_CHECKOUT_ROOT="/tmp/minimized_checkout_root"
    export MINIMIZED_CHECKOUT_REF="mock_ref"
    export CHECKOUT_ROOT="/tmp/checkout_root"
    export CHECKOUT_REF="mock_checkout_ref"
    export TO_REVISION="mock_to_revision"
    export FROM_REVISION="mock_from_revision"
    export EXTRACTED_DELTA_ROOT="/tmp/extracted_delta_root"
    export POD_NAME="mock_pod_name"
    export RESULTS_FROM_COMMIT_PATH="/tmp/results_from_commit_path"
    export RESULTS_TO_COMMIT_PATH="/tmp/results_to_commit_path"
    export RESULTS_EXTRACTED_DELTA_REF_PATH="/tmp/results_extracted_delta_ref_path"

    # Create necessary directories
    mkdir -p $EXTRACT_DELTA_CONSOLE_LOG_PATH
    mkdir -p $MINIMIZED_CHECKOUT_ROOT/$MINIMIZED_CHECKOUT_REF
    mkdir -p $CHECKOUT_ROOT/$CHECKOUT_REF
    mkdir -p $EXTRACTED_DELTA_ROOT/$POD_NAME

    # Mock git commands
    mock_git_rev_parse() {
        case "$1" in
        mock_from_revision) echo "mock_from_sha" ;;
        mock_to_revision) echo "mock_to_sha" ;;
        esac
    }

    mock_git_diff() {
        echo "file1.txt"
        echo "file2.txt"
        echo "file3.txt"
    }

    # Mock commands by overriding with functions
    git() {
        if [ "$1" = "rev-parse" ]; then
            mock_git_rev_parse "$2"
        elif [ "$1" = "diff" ]; then
            mock_git_diff "$@"
        fi
    }

    # Create mock files
    touch "$CHECKOUT_ROOT/$CHECKOUT_REF/file1.txt"
    touch "$CHECKOUT_ROOT/$CHECKOUT_REF/file2.txt"
    touch "$CHECKOUT_ROOT/$CHECKOUT_REF/file3.txt"

    # Create minimized checkout mock files
    touch "$MINIMIZED_CHECKOUT_ROOT/$MINIMIZED_CHECKOUT_REF/file1.txt"
    touch "$MINIMIZED_CHECKOUT_ROOT/$MINIMIZED_CHECKOUT_REF/file3.txt"
}

# Teardown mock environment
tearDown() {
    rm -rf /tmp/extract_delta_console_log
    rm -rf /tmp/minimized_checkout_root
    rm -rf /tmp/checkout_root
    rm -rf /tmp/extracted_delta_root
    rm -rf /tmp/results_from_commit_path
    rm -rf /tmp/results_to_commit_path
    rm -rf /tmp/results_extracted_delta_ref_path
}

# Test case: Run the script and verify outcomes
testScriptExecution() {
    # Run the script
    . ../scripts/extract-delta.sh

    # Check that files were copied correctly
    assertTrue "file1.txt should exist in extracted delta path" "[ -f $EXTRACTED_DELTA_ROOT/$POD_NAME/file1.txt ]"
    assertTrue "file3.txt should exist in extracted delta path" "[ -f $EXTRACTED_DELTA_ROOT/$POD_NAME/file3.txt ]"
    assertFalse "file2.txt should not exist in extracted delta path" "[ -f $EXTRACTED_DELTA_ROOT/$POD_NAME/file2.txt ]"

    # Check that commit SHAs were written to the correct paths
    assertEquals "mock_from_sha" "$(cat $RESULTS_FROM_COMMIT_PATH)"
    assertEquals "mock_to_sha" "$(cat $RESULTS_TO_COMMIT_PATH)"

    # Check that the POD_NAME was written to the correct path
    assertEquals "mock_pod_name" "$(cat $RESULTS_EXTRACTED_DELTA_REF_PATH)"
}

# Load and run shunit2
. ../../shunit2/shunit2/shunit2


I don't see any invocation  of testScriptExecution. Did you forget to show us line 1152? Also, you are invoking your script with a parameter, but we don't see where you would actually use it.

oh! I was in the idea that if i just call shunit2 it will automatically detect all 'test methods in the script

I don't know how shunit2 has been programmed, but since you tagged the question by shell, I believe this would be tricky to do in a POSIX shell. If it were written in i.e. bash or zsh, it at least could build an array of all functions, and then pick those which match a certain name. I don't see how this could be done in POSIX. But shunit2 is source code; why don't you simply look into it and see what it is doing?

Hi @user1934428 appreciate your comments. Yes as you mentioned I could have a look into the source code and found out I had done following mistakes in my code.
Double Loading of shunit2:

Location of the main function was wrong
Non-terminated git function
Issues with the script ../scripts/extract-delta.sh
Missing Directory Setup
Assertions for git commands output was wrong

Ones fixed the code is now executing. :)
